# How to set NODE_OPTIONS for all package.json scripts at once?

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg

I want to set `NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider` once for all scripts defined in my `package.json`, so I don't have to repeat myself and add it to each script individually.

Is there a way to do this? I tried putting it in `.env` file but it did not work.

I'm using Yarn v1.22.19.

Comment: You can set environment variables in your `.zshrc` or `.bash_profile` so it applies to everything after you start your shell.

Comment: @Evert locally — yes, but it's not an option for CI/prod

Comment: Of course environment variables are a thing in *any* place. `.env` was a thing that was invented many times after normal environment variables. Any operating system supports it. Any CI environment will have a way to set it.

Answer (score 3):

npm's config includes [`node-options`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/using-npm/config#node-options) (emphasis mine):

> Options to pass through to Node.js via the `NODE_OPTIONS` environment variable. This does not impact how npm itself is executed but **it does impact how lifecycle scripts are called**.

So you can create a [per-project `.npmrc` file](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/npmrc#per-project-config-file) (or add to an existing one) to set this for all scripts:

```
node-options=--openssl-legacy-provider
```

Comment: Thank you! This is probably a valid answer for npm.
I should have mentioned that I'm using yarn 1.22.19...

I checked that it does not work with yarn (neither in .npmrc or .yarnrc).

Comment: @ptkvsk I thought Classic Yarn _did_ follow `.npmrc`: https://yarnpkg.com/migration/guide#update-your-configuration-to-the-new-settings